# How to restrict Multiple dates selection in MonthCalender

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0, monthcalendar

I am use MonthCaalender to select a date

How to restrict Multiple dates selection in the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [MaxSelectionCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.maxselectioncount.aspx) property of the month calendar.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was too dumb to notice it :-).... was searching for something like 'Selectioncount'

Comment: i was not able to for 11 mins, i did later

Answer (score 0):

You can apply simple logic on MonthCaalender to remove selected date on mouse down event.
         Just use Mousedown and Clear all selection from moth calender.

Cheers!